# Upload an image (Base64) using Alamofire Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

Iam trying to upload 2 images to server with JSON request using alamofire

and here's my code :

```
   let parameters = ["CreditCardImage":CreditCardImage,"CreditCardBackImage":CreditCardBackImage , "CustomerID" : CustomerID]

            let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
                "Authorization": "Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==",
                "Accept": "application/json"
            ]



   Alamofire.request("MY URL", method : .post , parameters : parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default ,  headers: headers).responseJSON { response in

        // get json Response


        let json = JSON(response.result.value)

        print(json)


   }
```

When i print the response iam getting message <<  **unknown**  >> in the console

and i tried that in postman it's not working too what's wrong with that ? any help ?

Answer (score -1):

you should use other `Alamofire` methods. Here is an example:

```
func uploadAvatar(image: UIImage) {
    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1) {
            multipartFormData.append(imageData, withName: "file", fileName: "file.png", mimeType: "image/png")
        }
    }, to: self.serverAddress + "/user/uploadAvatar", method: .post, headers: ["Authorization": User.shared.token], encodingCompletion: { _ in })
}
```

Comment: Iam using multipartFormData with base64 too  ? 

and if yes how could i send it as a parameters  ?

Comment: @Muhamméd I assume you should check your server side to validate it gets image and does what you want.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

```
let image = UIImage.init(named: "myImage")
 let imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image!, 0.2)!

 let parameters = ["name": rname]

Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        multipartFormData.append(imgData, withName: "fileset",fileName: "file.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")
        for (key, value) in parameters {
                multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)
            }
    },
to:"mysite/upload.php")
{ (result) in
    switch result {
    case .success(let upload, _, _):

        upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
            print("Upload Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
        })

        upload.responseJSON { response in
             print(response.result.value)  
        }

    case .failure(let encodingError):
        print(encodingError)  
    }
}
```